# Proof of the integrability of the Thomae function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Consider the Thomae function $$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac1q, & \text{if }x\text{ is a rational number}\frac pq\text{, in lowest terms, with }q>0, \\
0, & \text{if }x\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$

How do I prove the following (where U stands for upper Riemann sum)?

> For each positive number $\epsilon$, there is a partition P of $[0,1]$
>   such that $$U(f,P)<\epsilon.$$

(This would then imply that $\int_0^1f=0$.)

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106488/upper-riemann-sum-of-a-function/106500) for the general idea.

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh, I've finally got it. Thanks!!!